# Audit trigger in sql azure

Tags: sql-server, triggers, azure-sql-database, select-into

I added a trigger to the table to copy the inserted data to an audit table.

- I got all the column names of the table from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
- I used "SELECT * INTO #INSERTED FROM INSERTED" to copy inserted data to a temporary table.
- Then used the following dynamic query to get the data from temporary table for each column.

  SET @sqlText = N'SELECT ' + @ColName + ' FROM #INSERTED'

where @ColName is the column name.

It was working fine with sql server 2008.
Now we moved to sql azure. `select into` is not supported in sql azure. I cannot create a temporary table and then use insert on it, as my table contains over 70 columns and also, I cannot use `INSERTED` table for a dynamic query.

So, please suggest any solution\workaround for it.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Azure V11 doesn't support select into. Please upgrade your server to SQL DB v12 and you should be able to do this.